# Black box optimization

Tags: optimization, nonconvex

I have a simulation which gives a scalar result depending on the choice of some continuous design variables. I am trying to minimize the output of the simulation. As a first step, I want to study the convexity of the problem. Is there a methodology that allows us to determine whether a black box function  (no analytical form) is convex or not ?

I have already found a pair $\{\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2\}$ that does not satisfy the midpoint convexity:

\begin{equation}
f(\vec{x}_1)+f(\vec{x}_2) \geq 2f\left(\frac{\vec{x}_1+\vec{x}_2}{2}\right)
\end{equation}

Is this a sufficient condition to say that the function is nonconvex ? Furthermore, if it is nonconvex how does that affect the choice of the optimizer ?

I have read that evolutionary algorithms could be a good choice for black box optimization. However, I do not have much experience in the field of optimization and I would appreciate it if someone could point me  in the right direction.

Comment: Yes. Convexity is defined as "for all points x1, x2, the following is true" and you've just found a pair of points for which it is not true -- so the function is not convex.

Comment: Does your black box produce deterministic results, i.e., not based on Monte Carlo simulation or subject to random error of whatever source?

Comment: Yes the black box produces deterministic results.

Comment: What is the dimensionality of the problem? Is anything known about the properties of the function - smooth or not, single maximum (or minimum) or multiple?

Comment: The dimensionality of the problem is 4. I do not know if the function is smooth or not and I  suspect that there might be multiple minima.

Comment: Ok, then if we need to guarantee that a global minimum is found then we would have to scan the whole domain, that would become expensive even in 4D. It would be useful to study the function, e.g., make some 1D plots to see what the behavior is. But as a practical method for a problem like this I would first try the Amoeba (downhill simplex) algorithm, available, e.g., in Numerical Recipes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried scanning a reasonable portion of the domain by evaluating the function at a grid of sample points and showed the result in a parallel coordinate plot. I have two main issues with that: First, I can't afford to compute the black box at a large number of sample points because my black-box is computationally expensive. Second, I am not sure how to interpret the results of the parallel coordinate plot. How can I use it to infer properties about the function (eg. multimodal).

Comment: Regarding the Amoeba method, I tried using the Nelder-Mead optimizer implemented in scipy. However, I forgot to mention that my problem is bounded and Nelder-Mead in scipy is unbounded. Do you know of any other direct search methods that implement bounds ?